# Save (or retrieve) the date I added a contact to Thunderbird's address book

Tags: thunderbird, contacts

I'd like to keep track of the date on which I add a contact to an address book on Thunderbird 52.1 (specifically, an address book that I keep synchronized with one on fruux.com using the Thunderbird extension Inverse SOGo Connector). Failing that, it would be nice to know the last modification date of a contact. Either would give me a sense of how old the contact information is.

If this information is already saved by Thunderbird, how can I retrieve it? If not, how can I cause it to be saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sfhowes pointed out](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=3031618&p=14755268#p14755268) that [the MoreFunctionsForAddressBook extension](https://freeshell.de//~kaosmos/morecols-en.html) can show the time a contact was last modified.